# proof of $\langle z,w\rangle =\overline{\langle w,z\rangle}$

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, inner-products

Here is an property of inner product space V: $\langle z,w\rangle =\overline{\langle w,z\rangle}$ (conjugate symmetry).

I need a reference on the proof of this property or general idea in proving this?

Comment: This is an axiom for inner products

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I see, that's why books are skipping proofs. Why does it hold true though? Just can't get the intuition.

Comment: There is nothing to prove. A positive definite bilinear function is *called* an inner product iff $\langle x,y\rangle =\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$ is true. Otherwise, *it is not called an inner product*

Comment: We can't tell you why it holds true in general. If you specify a particular inner product space then people can help you with this. Are there any examples of inner product spaces that you are familiar with, or will be studying?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC not right now, just curious about whether it is provable. Thanks!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Not quite *bi*linear, but rather *sesqui*linear (since $\langle ax,y\rangle=\overline a\langle x,y\rangle$).

Comment: @Gae.S. Oh yes of course, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the relation

$\langle z, w \rangle = \overline{\langle w, z \rangle } \tag 1$

is usually taken as an axiom; however, it is motivated by, and derives from, the corresponding property for the standard (hermitian) inner product on $\Bbb C^n$:

$\langle z, w \rangle = \displaystyle \sum_1^n \bar z_j w_j; \tag 2$

for this inner product we have

$\overline{\langle w, z \rangle} = \overline{ \displaystyle \sum_1^n \bar w_j z_j } = \sum_1^n  \bar{\bar w_j} \bar z_j = \sum_1^n w_j \bar z_j = \langle z, w \rangle. \tag 3$

The axiom (1) abstracts this to more general contexts in which $\Bbb C^n$ may not be directly available.

Also, see the comment by Arturo Magidin below.

Comment: tt should be noted that there is a divide among mathematicians on what is “the” standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$; your is linear in the second variable and conjugate linear in the first, but many authors define a sesquilinear inner product to be linear in the first coordinate.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  duly noted.  I'm trying to keep it simple here.  ***Cheers!***

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:  anyway, you saved me a little typing.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $w, z \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Using the additive properties of complex conjugation,
$$
\langle z, w \rangle
 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} z_i \overline{w}_i
 = \overline{\overline{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} z_i \overline{w}_i}}
 = \overline{\sum_{i = 1}^n \overline{z_i \overline{w}_i}}
 = \overline{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \overline{z}_i w_i}
 = \overline{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} w_i \overline{z}_i}
 = \overline{\langle w, z \rangle}
$$